# MongoDBで全角半角の区別なしで検索することはできますか？

Tags: mongodb

正規表現で大文字、小文字の区別なしで検索する方法はわかったのですが

```
db.stuff.find( { foo: /^bar$/i } );
```

全角半角区別なしで検索する方法が見つかりません。
方法はございますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

生データのフィールドとは別に検索用フィールドを新しく追加して、生データを検索用に変換して挿入しておけばいんじゃないですかね。この場合は、全角と大文字をすべて半角小文字にして検索用フィールドに追加するプログラムを回し終えてから、検索の時は検索用フィールドを使えば、空間効率は悪いですが解決できます。